# Android dismiss keyboard

Tags: android

How do I dismiss the keyboard when a button is pressed?

Comment: Make a EditText Focusable = False does the job. Do you want to disable it completely?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

You want to disable or dismiss a virtual Keyboard?

If you want to just dismiss it you can use the following lines of code in your button's on click Event

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Two problems with this.... one is that myEditText needs to be Final. Second is that I have to know which EditText box has the focus. Any solution to this?

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles here, you can use the activity's (either the activity you are in or the fragments `getActivity()`) `getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken()` for the first arg to `hideSoftInputFromWindow()`. Also, do it in the `onPause()` and not the `onStop()` if you are trying to get it to go away when changing activities.

Comment: This answer, combined with the comment up here, totally solved my problem!

Comment: What an ugly, ugly approach to dismiss a keyboard. I hope there's a cleaner way in the future to do such a simple thing.

Answer (score 80):

The solution above doesn't work for all device and moreover it's using EditText as a parameter. This is my solution, just call this simple method:

```
private void hideSoftKeyBoard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if(imm.isAcceptingText()) { // verify if the soft keyboard is open                      
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `isAcceptingText()` made this answer better than others

Comment: Good solution... in rare cases isAcceptingText() can return false when the keyboard is still on the screen, for example click away from EditText to text that can be selected but not edited in the same window.

Answer (score 31):

This is my solution

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    View v = activity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
    if (v != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is if you know the view that has caused the keyboard to show.

Answer (score 16):

you can also use this code on button click event

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a Kotlin solution (mixing the various answers in thread)

Create an extension function (perhaps in a common ViewHelpers class)

```
fun Activity.dismissKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE ) as InputMethodManager
    if( inputMethodManager.isAcceptingText )
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( this.currentFocus.windowToken, /*flags:*/ 0)
}
```

Then simply consume using:

```
// from activity
this.dismissKeyboard()

// from fragment
activity.dismissKeyboard()
```

Answer (score 5):

The first solution with InputMethodManager worked like a champ for me, the getWindow().setSoftInputMode method did not on android 4.0.3 HTC Amaze.

@Ethan Allen, I did not need to make the edit text final.  Maybe you are using an EditText inner class that you declared the containing method?  You could make the EditText a class variable of the Activity.  Or just declare a new EditText inside the inner class / method and use findViewById() again.  Also, I didn't find that I needed to know which EditText in the form had focus.  I could just pick one arbitrarily and use it.  Like so:

```
    EditText myEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.anyEditTextInForm);  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4):

```
    public static void hideSoftInput(Activity activity) {
    try {
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) return;
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        if (window == null) return;
        View view = window.getCurrentFocus();
        //give decorView a chance
        if (view == null) view = window.getDecorView();
        if (view == null) return;

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm == null || !imm.isActive()) return;
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Solution make sure that it hides keyboard also do nothing if it not opened.
It uses extension so it can be used from any Context Owner class.

```
fun Context.dismissKeyboard() {
    val imm by lazy { this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager }
    val windowHeightMethod = InputMethodManager::class.java.getMethod("getInputMethodWindowVisibleHeight")
    val height = windowHeightMethod.invoke(imm) as Int
    if (height > 0) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

some edits in above solutions and worked

```
private void hideSoftKeyBoard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) { // verify if the soft keyboard is open
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the context of the view, we can achieve the desired outcome with the following extension methods in Kotlin:

```
/**
 * Get the [InputMethodManager] using some [Context].
 */
fun Context.getInputMethodManager(): InputMethodManager {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return getSystemService(InputMethodManager::class.java)
    }

    return getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
}

/**
 * Dismiss soft input (keyboard) from the window using a [View] context.
 */
fun View.dismissKeyboard() = context
        .getInputMethodManager()
        .hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                windowToken
                , 0
        )
```

Once these are in place, just call:

```
editTextFoo.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin:

To dismiss the keyboard, call `clearFocus()` on the respective element when the button is clicked.

Example:

```
mSearchView.clearFocus()
```