# how to disable popup of android keypad using jquery?

Tags: jquery, android, popup, keypad

I have a webpage with custom jquery-based 7keypad .
while opening this page , text field gets focussed and android keypad gets popup.
How to disable popup of android keypad using jQuery ?

webpage is http://k777g77.hpage.com/

Comment: I have no experience with jQuery, but my guess is that the Android system does not make it possible for code on a webpage to affect the soft keyboard. Even for something simple as hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hide the keyboard on the Android side by using something like:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

or

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553779/android-dismiss-keyboard) post for more info.